# Constant String "UTF_8" causes a warning in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Consider this code at the beginning of the class:

```
private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF_8";
```

Android studio seems having some kind of problem:

[image]

It's not a blocking error (is it a warning?) I can compile and execute.

But I wondering why it's shown as error.

I'm using a constant to call `URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some problem with the Android Studio. Btw I have defined same constant but do not see any error in the Android studio I am using right now. Try 'invalidating cache & restart'.

Don't use your own string, there is built-in constant for this

```
android.util.Xml.Encoding.UTF_8
```

First import Xml;

```
import android.util.Xml;
```

and then

```
URLEncoder.encode(String, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8);
```

Comment: He is not asking how to avoid the warning, he is asking why he is having that warning

Comment: Why are you defining your own constant?

Comment: I am not defining anything, it is not my question, but you are not answering what he is asking for

Comment: URLEncoder.encode() wants a string that define th charsetName

Comment: Agreed, use android.util.Xml.Encoding.UTF_8 for UTF-8 charset